# Proof of conditional entropy $H( X , Y | Z ) = H( X | Z ) + H( Y | X , Z )$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, information-theory, entropy

In information theory, the joint entropy $H(X,Y)$ of a pair of discrete random variables $(X,Y)$ is defined as:

$$
H(X,Y) = -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}p(x,y)log_2p(x,y)\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

And the conditional entropy $H(Y \mid X)$ of the same $(X,Y)$ as:

$$
H(Y \mid X) = -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}p(x,y)log_2p(y\mid x)\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

With the chain rule of probability, the theorem:

$$
H(X,Y) = H(X)+H(Y \mid X)\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$

is another interpretation of the joint entropy for $(X,Y)$.

A corollary of this theorem is:
$$
H(X,Y \mid Z) = H(X \mid Z)+H(Y \mid X,Z)
$$

Proof:

\begin{align}
H(X,Y \mid Z) &= -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)log_2p(x,y \mid z) \\
  &= -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)log_2p(y \mid z,x)p(x\mid z) \\
  &= -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y, z)log_2p(x\mid z) -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)log_2p(y \mid z,x)\\
&= -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(y\mid x,z)p(x,z)log_2p(x\mid z) -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)log_2p(y \mid z,x)\\
&= -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,z)log_2p(x\mid z) -\sum_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)log_2p(y \mid z,x)\\
&= H(X \mid Z)+H(Y \mid X,Z)
\end{align}

I would like to know if it is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having looked at the details of your proof, I suggest the following alternative argument.

Instead of seeing $X$ and $Z$ as two distinct discrete random variables, we pair them up and interpret $A := (X,Z)$ as a single random variable. Clearly, all information that is contained in $X$ and $Z$ is also contained in $A$ and vice versa. Similarly, we pair up $X$ and $Y$ by defining $B : = (X,Y)$. We then get by applying rule $(3)$:

$$ H(X \vert Z) + H(Y \vert X,Z) =$$ 
$$ H(X \vert Z) + H(Y \vert A) =$$ 
$$ H(X,Z) -H(Z) + H(Y,A) - H(A) =$$
$$ H(X,Z) -H(Z) + H(Y,A) - H(X,Z) =$$ 
$$ -H(Z) + H(Y,A)=$$
$$ -H(Z) + H(Y,X,Z)=$$
$$ -H(Z) + H(B,Z)=$$
$$ H(B \vert Z) =$$
$$ H(X,Y \vert Z).$$

Comment: Yes, this is another proof for the corollary. By the way of how you developed the proof, IMO, it's less easy to read if it starts by the end of the proof, rather than the beginning.

Comment: Thats subjective ;-) I feel its easier and more natural in this direction. Generally, if you want to prove an identiy $A = B$ where $A$ is easy and $B$ is complicated, as a rule of thumb, it is more advisable to start with $B$.

Comment: Even if it's not a verification of the proof in the OP, I'll acept this as a better answer.

Comment: Great! Your proof is perfectly correct too, by the way, except for a small typo in the third line, where you accidentally made a $\vert$ instead of a "," between $y$ and $z$ in the first sum. So what you meant was $p(x,y,z)$ instead of $p(x,y \vert z)$.

Answer (score 2):

$H(X,Y) = -\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}p(x,y)\log_2p(x,y)$

$H(X,Y∣Z)=−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2p(x,y∣z)$

$H(X,Y∣Z)=−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2(\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(x,z)})(\frac{p(x,z)}{p(z)})$

$=−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2p(y∣z,x)p(x∣z)$

$=−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2p(x∣z)−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2p(y∣x,z)$

$=−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,z)\log_2p(x∣z)−\sum\limits_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Y}\sum\limits_{y\in \mathcal Z}p(x,y,z)\log_2p(y∣x,z)
\\= H(X∣Z)+H(Y∣X,Z)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).